# javascript onClick event in setAttribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar and when we click on next month/year all table's td field is refreshed.

When all data is refreshed I also want that the `onClick` should also get the new data.

The code for refreshing is below

```
 function updateCells(firstTime) {
//alert('called');
var startYear = t.start.getFullYear();
var today = clearTime(new Date());
var cell;
var date;
var row;
subTables.each(function(i, _sub){
var d = cloneDate(t.start);
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear(),i,1);
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear(),i,1-d.getDay());
$(_sub).find('td').each(function(ii, _cell) {

    cell = $(_cell);
    if (d.getMonth() == i) {
        cell.removeClass('fc-other-month');
    }else{
        cell.addClass('fc-other-month');
    }
    if (+d == +today && d.getMonth() == i) {
        cell.addClass(tm + '-state-highlight fc-today');
    }else{
        cell.removeClass(tm + '-state-highlight fc-today');
    }
    cell.find('div.fc-day-number').text(d.getDate());
    cell.find('div.fc-day-number').setAttribute('onClick','clicked("' + d.getDate() + '"');
    //document.getElementsByTagName('div.fc-day-number').setAttribute('onClick','clicked("' + d.getDate() + '"');
    addDays(d, 1);
});
});
bodyRows.filter('.fc-year-have-event').removeClass('fc-year-have-event');
 }
```

The error is

```
TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName(...).setAttribute is not a function
```

Does anybody knows how to set the new data in onClick event.

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName('div.fc-day-number') is array

Comment: @salexch No its not array, but the same name is used for each div.

Comment: cell.find('div.fc-day-number').onClick jquery doesnt have method onClick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getElementsByTagName()` function returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList), which is a collection of nodes, so you'll need to iterate over it and act on each one separately.

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName(...);
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    var node = nodes[i];
    node.setAttribute(...);
}
```

Though I don't believe that function is designed or intended to work with a full selector, only a tag name (so `'div'` and not `'div.fc-day-number'`).

You could, instead, do it this way:

```
cell.find('div.fc-day-number').off('click').click(function(e) {
   clicked(d.getDate());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.But i can't implement this, Can you give answer in this format `cell.find('div.fc-day-number').setAttribute('onClick','clicked("' + d.getDate() + '"');`.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Being inside a `.each()` call doesn't prevent you from using a loop, they *can* be nested. That said, I've added a jQuery method for binding the click event handlers; without knowing the scope of `d` you *might* run into issues, I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = 0;
$(_sub).find('td').each(function(ii, _cell) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('div.fc-day-number')[i].setAttribute('onClick','clicked("' + d.getDate() + '"');
    i++;
});
```

.each() is also a loop you just have to declare a variable and increment.